# SQL: Convert Data For One Column To Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tried looking for a solution to my problem using things such as Pivot, but they do not seem to give the output for which I am looking as they appear to map specific values in a row to a column.

I have two columns, the first which contains a "key" field and the second which is changing data.  e.g.

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════╗
║ Project  ║     Location     ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ ProjectA ║ \\Server1\Share1 ║
║ ProjectA ║ \\Server2\Share1 ║
║ ProjectB ║ \\Server6\Share2 ║
║ ProjectB ║ \\Server1\Share2 ║
║ ProjectB ║ \\Server2\Share3 ║
║ ProjectC ║ \\Server8\Share2 ║
║ ProjectD ║ \\Server5\Share9 ║
║ ProjectD ║ \\ServerX\ShareY ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

The output that I am trying to achieve is as follows:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦═════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ Project  ║     Column1      ║     Column2      ║     Column3      ║ Column4 ║ Column5  ║ ColumnX ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ ProjectA ║ \\Server1\Share1 ║ \\Server2\Share1 ║ NULL             ║ NULL    ║ NULL     ║         ║
║ ProjectB ║ \\Server1\Share2 ║ \\Server2\Share3 ║ \\Server6\Share2 ║ NULL    ║ NULL     ║         ║
║ ProjectC ║ \\Server8\Share2 ║ NULL             ║ NULL             ║ NULL    ║ NULL     ║         ║
║ ProjectD ║ \\Server5\Share9 ║ \\ServerX\ShareY ║ NULL             ║ NULL    ║ NULL     ║         ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩═════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

If there is no data for the column then it will be NULL.

The number of distinct values in the location column is dynamic and the desired output is a generic column name, with the distinct location value beside the corresponding Project value.

Hopefully someone can help me with this problem as it is driving me mad!

Thanks in advance.

Ninja

Comment: Why for `PROJECT D` you have 2 records in result? And not one record `ProjectD
\\Server5\Share9
\\ServerX\ShareY`

Comment: That was my mistake, it went off the bottom of the box so I did not notice it.  Have updated the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Warning:**

This solution assume that it will be max 6 column, you can add more for example up to 20.

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374760)**

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable(
   Project  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL 
  ,Location VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectA','\\Server1\Share1');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectA','\\Server2\Share1');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectB','\\Server6\Share2');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectB','\\Server1\Share2');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectB','\\Server2\Share3');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectC','\\Server8\Share2');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectD','\\Server5\Share9');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectD','\\ServerX\ShareY');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectD','\\ServerX\ShareY');
```

Query:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT Project, Location,
    [rn] = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Project ORDER BY Location)
  FROM #mytable
)
SELECT
   Project
  ,Column1 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Location ELSE NULL END)
  ,Column2 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Location ELSE NULL END)
  ,Column3 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Location ELSE NULL END)
  ,Column4 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN Location ELSE NULL END)
  ,Column5 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN Location ELSE NULL END)
  ,Column6 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN Location ELSE NULL END)
  -- ....
  --  ,ColumnX = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = X THEN Location ELSE NULL END)
FROM cte
GROUP BY Project;
```

## EDIT:

Truly generic solution that uses Dynamic-SQL and generates Pivoted column list:

**[LiveDemo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374823)**

```
DECLARE @cols  NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @cols_piv NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@max  INT = 0;

SELECT @max = MAX(c)
FROM (
  SELECT Project, COUNT(DISTINCT Location) AS c
  FROM #mytable
  GROUP BY Project) AS s;


SET @cols = STUFF(     
            (SELECT ',' +  CONCAT('[',c.n, '] AS Column',c.n, ' ')
            FROM  ( SELECT TOP (1000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY n)AS c(n)
            WHERE c.n <= @max
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @cols_piv = STUFF(
            (SELECT ',' +  CONCAT('[',c.n, '] ')
            FROM  ( SELECT TOP (1000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY n)AS c(n)
            WHERE c.n <= @max
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');        

-- SELECT @cols;

set @query = N'SELECT Project, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Project, Location,
                [rn] = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Project ORDER BY Location)
                from #mytable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Location)
                for rn in (' + @cols_piv + ')
            ) p ';

-- SELECT @query; 

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
    @query;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response lad2025.  Very helpful.  In order to scale it, you mention using Dynamic-SQL to generate a pivoted column list.  Do you have an example of roughly what that would look like?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Ninja See updated answer, fully dynamic-solution ;)

Comment: one thing that I do notice is that I get strange results if I don't group the ranking table as it just repeats data.  The minor change below fixed the issue.    `WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT
 Project
 , WS
 , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Project ORDER BY Location) [RN]
FROM #mytable
GROUP BY PROJECT, Location`

Comment: @Ninja Sorry I don't understand. Please fork my query and provide link with sample. In your data there is no column `WS`. I hope that it works for your data.

Comment: that was my mistake.  WS is in the table that I am using.  WS should be Location.  `WITH CTE AS (SELECT Project , Location, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Project ORDER BY Location) [RN] FROM #mytable GROUP BY PROJECT, Location`.  As I am a new user, I don't think I am able to fork the query as I only have limited options.  Also, sorry to be a pain, but I am running SSMS 2005 so don't have the `CONCAT` function.

Comment: @Ninja Ok, but I hope you get the result as you want, right?

Comment: Yes, I get the correct results by adding the Group By.  Is there an easy way to achieve the dynamic SQL without using CONCAT?  Thanks.

Comment: @Ninja You can change concat to `+` if you are using SQL Server2008.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @lad2025.  I have managed to get it to run now.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to @lad2025.

I am using Server2005 so these are the modifications that I had to make to get this to work for me:

- Couldn't declare and assign a variable in the same line.  `@max INT = 0;`
- `CONCAT` function doesn't exist so replaced with + between the parameters.  `', ' +  '[' + convert(varchar, c.n) + '] AS Column' + c.n`
- c.n is of type bigint so I had to `CONVERT` it to `VARCHAR` - `CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.n)`
- When generating the table on which to pivot, a `GROUP BY` needs to be provided otherwise the data appears in a strange column number.

**Without `GROUP BY`**
Without the `GROUP BY` as more data is in the initial `#mytable` the results display in columns that are not sequential.

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════╦══════════════════╦══════╗
║ Project  ║       Col1       ║       Col2       ║       Col3       ║ Col4 ║       Col5       ║ Col6 ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════╬══════════════════╬══════╣
║ ProjectA ║ \\Server1\Share1 ║ \\Server2\Share1 ║ NULL             ║ NULL ║ NULL             ║ NULL ║
║ ProjectB ║ \\Server1\Share2 ║ \\Server2\Share3 ║ \\Server6\Share2 ║ NULL ║ NULL             ║ NULL ║
║ ProjectC ║ \\Server8\Share2 ║ NULL             ║ NULL             ║ NULL ║ NULL             ║ NULL ║
║ ProjectD ║ NULL             ║ \\Server5\Share9 ║ NULL             ║ NULL ║ \\ServerX\ShareY ║ NULL ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════╩══════════════════╩══════╝
```

**With `GROUP BY`**  As it should be.

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ Project  ║       Col1       ║       Col2       ║       Col3       ║ Col4 ║ Col5 ║ Col6 ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ ProjectA ║ \\Server1\Share1 ║ \\Server2\Share1 ║ NULL             ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
║ ProjectB ║ \\Server1\Share2 ║ \\Server2\Share3 ║ \\Server6\Share2 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
║ ProjectC ║ \\Server8\Share2 ║ NULL             ║ NULL             ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
║ ProjectD ║ \\Server5\Share9 ║ \\ServerX\ShareY ║ NULL             ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

**Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable(
   Project  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL 
  ,Location VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectA','\\Server1\Share1');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectA','\\Server2\Share1');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectB','\\Server6\Share2');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectB','\\Server1\Share2');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectB','\\Server2\Share3');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectC','\\Server8\Share2');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectD','\\Server5\Share9');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Project,Location) VALUES ('ProjectD','\\ServerX\ShareY');
```

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @cols  NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @cols_piv NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@max  INT;

SELECT @max = MAX(c)
FROM (
  SELECT Project, COUNT(DISTINCT Location) AS c
  FROM #mytable
  GROUP BY Project) AS s;

SET @cols = STUFF(     
            (SELECT ', ' +  '[' + convert(varchar, c.n) + '] AS Column' + convert(varchar, c.n)
            FROM  ( SELECT TOP (1000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY n)AS c(n)
            WHERE c.n <= @max
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @cols_piv = STUFF(
            (SELECT ',' +  '[' + convert(varchar, c.n) + ']'
            FROM  ( SELECT TOP (1000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY n)AS c(n)
            WHERE c.n <= @max
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');        

set @query = N'SELECT Project, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Project, Location,
                [rn] = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Project ORDER BY Location)
                from #mytable
                GROUP BY Project, Location
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Location)
                for rn in (' + @cols_piv + ')
            ) p ';

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
    @query;
```